# Javascript to check for certain time and return UTC timezone

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I am runnning Javascript code on a server using a schedule (cron job). I need to check for a certain time (i.e. 8AM) in every timezone every hour. Below is an example of workflow

1. it is currently 13:00 UTC time
2. job runs and executes javascript code (since it runs on an hourly schedule)
3. javascript function checks which timezone (UTC) is currently between 7:58-8:02 (the 4 minutes timespan is just in case of a time delay and clock inaccuracy)
4. the code finds that (UTC-5:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) is currently 8:00 and prints the result like 'UTC-5:00'
5. then, repeats this same process all over again at the next hour (14:00) - it would find that (UTC-6) Central Time is currently 8:00AM

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I don't need any of the job scheduling stuff. I already have the cron script necessary to run the script. What I am struggling with is the Javascript portion.

Comment: @cracker: While it's good to try and improve posts, please keep in mind that inline code spans (`like this`) are only meant for code within sentences, not for highlighting or emphasising a word. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A problem i see is that you don't have a list of timezones that you care about. In fact i don't even see a good way of obtaining a list of official (or not official) timezones at all, in Javascript. Note that if you run once every 60 minutes you might miss 'odd' timezones such as New Delhi's (they are off by 30 minutes relative to most timezones). So the first step would be to somehow get a list of timezones that you care about. I see 2 methods for this:

1. Make a list of timezones - simply an array of objects, or something like that, that contain the name of the timezones and their offsets to UTC. Then you can make your checks by constructing Date objects and adding/subtracting these predefined offsets. See the getMinutes(), getHours(), setMinutes(), setHours(), getUTCMinutes(), getUTCHours(), setUTCMinutes(), setUTCHours() functions of Date [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).
2. Use the moment.js library and this [timezone builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) they have. Personally i've never used this library so i don't know much about it. You can also check out [this nice map](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: +1.  There are also time zones that are 45 minute offset, such as Nepal.